# How to generate SQL query from Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

Simple question - how can I view the SQL query that alteryx is using to run my workflow?

I've googled and found info about a 'dynamic output' node, but I can't find that node in alteryx - it might be in a previous version?

Answer (score 1):

A couple answers:

- If you are using In-DB tools, then the "Dynamic Output In-DB" tool will allow you to grab the query being utilized at that stage of the workflow. If you cannot locate this tool (e.g. maybe that tool category is hidden), type "dynamic" in the "Search all tools" box... it should be found.
- If you are not using In-DB tools, then the "workflow" simply isn't taking place in the database: there is no query to speak of. In this case, the best you can do is look at your Input tool(s) and look at an embedded query that can be utilized as part of the initial data grab. (See config panel for the Input Tool, "Table or Query" property, which will open a dialog with a "Query Editor" tab... that will show the query used during input).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the In-database tool? These tools generate SQL in the back-end and you can extract this using the Dynamic output in-db tool.

If you are using the tools outside of the in-database category, these will not generate SQL code a they are in-memory processes.

Answer (score 0):

It may be in the Input Data tool if you have a SQL connection..

If you use PASW(SPSS) Modeler then it compiles workflow to SQL as much as it can...